# Finding linear equation from $3$ vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I was given the question above. Looking at that I tried to make the vectors into parametric equations and then solve them. The problem I encountered is that

1) $x = -3$, a constant and

2) There's $2$ solutions to the last $2$ columns: $z= -3+5a$ and $t= 4+3a$

How do I go from this step to creating a linear equation?

Comment: Please take the time to include _all_ of the relevant parts of your question as text instead of pasting images of your homework/exam problem. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable, nor accessible to screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\u\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-1\\-3\\4\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0\\5\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\5\\3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus

\begin{align*}
x&=-3a\\
y&=-a+5b\\
z&=-3a+5c\\
u&=4a+3c
\end{align*}
From the last two equations we get $5u-3z=29a$. Now using the first equation we get
$$\frac{29x}{3}-3z+5u=0.$$
From the second equation we get that $y \in \Bbb{R}$ (because $b$ can take any arbitrary real value). So
$$\color{red}{\frac{29x}{3}+0(y)-3z+5u=0}.$$

Comment: So I have to give all 3 vectors a scalar multiple, I see. I thought that I should only give a scalar multiple to the last 2 vectors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CipherBot Span means all possible linear combinations. So span$\{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\}=\{c_1\mathbf{x}+c_2\mathbf{y} \, | \, c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for an hyperplane $ax+by+cz+dw=0$ through the origin such that the normal vector $(a,b,c,d)$ is orthogonal to the vectors $\vec{a_1},\vec{a_2},\vec{a_3}$ (which are linearly independent), that is
$$\begin{cases}   
-3a-b-3c+4d=0   \\
5b=0\\
5c+3d=0
\end{cases}  
$$
Hence after solving the system, we find that$(a,b,c,d)=(29/3,0,-3,5)$ works.

Answer (score 0):

The three given vectors are obviously linearly independent. If you add to the set $\{\vec a_1,\vec a_2,\vec a_3\}$ any other vector $\vec v = [x,y,z,u]$ that lies in their span, the resulting set of four vectors is linearly dependent. Therefore, $$\det\begin{bmatrix}\vec v\\\vec a_1\\\vec a_2\\\vec a_3\end{bmatrix} = \det\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&u\\-3&-1&-3&4\\0&5&0&0\\0&0&5&3\end{bmatrix}=0$$ holds for any such vector, and the determinant obviously vanishes when $\vec v$ is equal to any of the three given vectors, so this is a linear equation for this subspace of $\mathbb R^4$. I expect that you’ll have to present it in a different form, though, but I’ll leave it to you to expand this determinant and rearrange as desired.